# Debugging SAS error message "ERROR: Cannot retrieve metadata from SAS Metadata Repository."

Tags: sas, sas-metadata

I get the above error when submitting code as follows:

```
337   data x;
338   set nz.aa;
ERROR: Cannot retrieve metadata from SAS Metadata Repository.
339   run;
```

The NZ library is on a Netezza server accessed via UNIX (libname engine), SAS 9.1.3.  Our signon script is automated and not easily visible.

What is the most likely cause of such a message, and/or how can further detail be obtained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd first check to see that the user running the code has permissions in metadata to read the library.  That seems the most likely culprit to me.

Comment: and how would you check that?

Comment: Can you connect to the metadata server with SAS Management Console and look at the library manager plugin?  http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/91pdf/sasdoc_913/mgmtconsole_ug_9952.pdf

Comment: Don't have an SMC account - just Base SAS :(